# A question about passing data between 2 views by sheet modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, presentation

I present a view by sheet modifier, like this:

```
@State private var taskId:Int64 = 0

Button("Click me") {
    self.taskId = task.id               // the value of task.id is: 20220523125600
    print("self.taskId:\(self.taskId)")   // print: self.taskId: 20220520153944
    self.showTaskEditView = true
}
.sheet(
    isPresented: $showTaskEditView,
    onDismiss: {
        reloadList()
    }, content: {
        TestView(taskId: $taskId)
    }
)
```

but when I print the value of taskId to debug, first time I click button, it output like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var taskId:Int64
    @State var task:Task? = nil
    
    public init(taskId:Binding<Int64>){
        self._taskId = taskId
        print("taskId:\(taskId.wrappedValue)")   // print: taskId:0
        print("self.taskId:\(self.taskId)")      // print: self.taskId:0
        
        self._task = .init(initialValue: TaskRepository().getItem(id: self.taskId))
        
        print("self.task:\(self.task)")  // print:State<Optional<Task>>(_value: nil, _location: nil)
    }

    // other code .......
}
```

but second time I click button, it output like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var taskId:Int64
    @State var task:Task? = nil
    
    public init(taskId:Binding<Int64>){
        self._taskId = taskId
        print("taskId:\(taskId.wrappedValue)")   // print: taskId:20220523125600
        print("self.taskId:\(self.taskId)")      // print: self.taskId:20220523125600
        
        self._task = .init(initialValue: TaskRepository().getItem(id: self.taskId))
        
        print("self.task:\(self.task)")  // print:State<Optional<Task>>(_value: Optional(<Task: 0x60000393ed00> (entity: Task; id:........
    }

    // other code .......
}
```

WHY it print like this ? Where is the wrong code ?

Comment: try using the `.sheet(item: ...)` version of sheet. There is some info on this at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Comment: thank you, using .sheet(item: ...) is effective